# Export to excel in php. Table values changed in excel

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php.
I am trying to export my mysql table to excel with the help of below code. This is working file, but in Table1 I am having column1 that is having values like 0010,0020,0030,0040. but when I have exported it to excel then this column in excel having values as 10,20,30,40. I want to keep values as it is in excel file also.

Please help.

Thanks.

```
<?php
include 'db-config.php';
session_start();
$course=$_SESSION['course'];
$entry_year=$_SESSION['entry_year'];

$query="select CAST(s.column1 AS CHAR(20)) AS 'column1', m.* 
from Table1 s LEFT JOIN Table2 m ON s.id=m.id";

$header = '';
$data ='';
$export = mysql_query ($query) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";

?>
```

Comment: Simply naming a file *.xls does not magically make it an excel fille

Comment: It is working properly and exporting my table data to excel file. But the problem here is, my data is modified. 00 is removed from data in excel file. This file is executed on my HTML form submission.

Comment: Try sending this field to excel with a leading apostrophe.

Comment: unless you write an actual xls file (most of use use: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel ) you will never know what results you and your users may get.